# Unable to enter null value in bigint or double datatype in mariadb table using python

Tags: mysql, sql, python-3.x, mariadb

I am inserting records in maria db table from a file using python. Input file has header. Population and Avg_Height columns in the file are partial empty. I want it to go as null value in table as well. Population column in table is set as bigint(20) and can accept null value. I am trying the below code -

```
Table Definition - 
CREATE TABLE `local_db`.`table_x` (
  `Unique_code` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `population` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Avg_Height` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `Govt` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

```
try:
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                         database='local_db',
                                         user='root',
                                         password='root',
                                         port = '3306')

    input_file = "input_file"
    csv_data = csv.reader(open(input_file))
    next(csv_data)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    for row in csv_data:
        cursor.execute("""
        INSERT INTO table_x(Unique_code,city,state,population,Avg_Height,Govt)
        VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE city = VALUES(city),state = VALUES(state), \
        population = VALUES(population),Avg_Height = VALUES(Avg_Height),Govt = VALUES(Govt)""")
    connection.commit()
    print(cursor.rowcount, "Record inserted successfully into table_x")
    cursor.close()

except mysql.connector.Error as error:
    print("Failed to insert record into table_x table {}".format(error))



finally:
    if (connection.is_connected()):
        connection.close()
        print("MySQL connection is closed")
```

But I am getting below error -

```
Failed to insert record into table_x table 1366 (22007): Incorrect integer value: '' for column `local_db`.`table_x`.`population` at row 1
MySQL connection is closed
```

Please suggest what code changes I can do here to handle this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to insert `null` instead of `''` empty string. here is the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/g3u7Gv7QasTiAkNsRorgg/0).

```
CREATE TABLE `table_x` (
  `Unique_code` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `population` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Avg_Height` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `Govt` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL
) ;

INSERT INTO table_x(Unique_code,city,state,population,Avg_Height,Govt)
values
('xyz','abc','dd',null ,3, 'fd');
```

Comment: Can you please explain how to handle this in file.

Comment: @VikrantKumar Before inserting into the table you can try replacing `''` with null once you open the CSV file .

Answer (score 1):

You need to insert `NULL` in that situation instead of an empty string. You can pre-process the `row` list to convert empty strings into `None`, which will have the same effect:

```
for row in csv_data:
    row = [None if v == '' else v for v in row]
    # write to table
```